# Read output from a subprocess executed by Python

Tags: python, comparative-review, io, child-process

I've written these 2 methods and I'm wondering if the 2nd method, which uses yield is more efficient or if I'm using yield wrong. Can someone refactor the 2nd method to make it more efficient for reading system os calls with large output?

```
def exec_cmd(command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
                            shell=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    return_code = proc.returncode

    if stderr:
        raise Error(stdout, stderr)

    if return_code:
        raise Error(stdout, return_code)

    return stdout, return_code


def exec_cmd_output_line_by_line(command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
                            shell=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    return_code = proc.returncode

    if return_code:
        raise Error(proc.stdout, return_code)

    for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
        yield line.strip()
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have a bug.  You gave `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.  That means exactly what it says: stderr will be redirected to stdout.  Because of that, `stderr` will always be `None` and `stdout` will be assigned to whatever the errors are.  Test it yourself with something like `ls --qaz`.  What you should have said is `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`.

It is difficult to do a comparative review because the two functions do not do quite the same thing.  I will, however, do a review of the second function.

---

I don't see a need to create a temporary `return_code` variable.  Just check `if proc.returncode:` instead.

You don't account for the cases when there is an error.  What you used in the first function looks pretty good.  I would use a different exception class so that functions that call this function can handle the different types of exceptions in different ways.

File objects are iterable.  That means that your last loop can be shortened to this:

```
for line in proc.stdout:
    yield line.strip()
```

That prevents reading all of the lines into memory.  You could also use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), though it wouldn't be very efficient in Python 2 (because it creates a complete list instead of a generator):

```
return map(str.strip, proc.stdout)
```

Another option is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
return (line.strip() for line in proc.stdout)
```